# Subclassing UIView to draw in Quartz

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to draw a figure in my iPhone application using Quartz 2D. I understand that I have to do this by subclassing UIView and overriding the drawRect function. I'm trying to follow [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_Graphics_Drawing_Tutorial_using_Quartz_2D) tutorial to do this but I can't get it to work.

It seems subclassing UIView does not create a .xib-file like the tutorial seem to imply. Subclassing UIViewController (I know this is wrong but I tried it anyway) does create a .xib-file but does not seem to have the drawRect-function.

Has anyone any experience in this, or knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance,
Tobias Tovedal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a `UIView` subclass and put your drawing code in its `drawRect:` method. You don't need a NIB file (why would you if you draw the view yourself?).
2. In a view controller, create an instance of your custom view class, set the view's frame and add it to the view controller's view with: `[self.view addSubview:myCustomView];`.
3. There is no step 3.