# How to draw on UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subclassing UIView to draw in Quartz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398911/subclassing-uiview-to-draw-in-quartz)

Hello i am searching good example how to draw something on UIView, UIScrollView ... using QuartzCore.

For first try i want to draw a triangle or even a line on some view. Is it possible this implement in UIVIewController ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to subclass a UIView, have your UIViewController add an instance of the subclass as a visible sub view, and call setNeedsDisplay on it.  Then, when the drawRect method of your UIView subclass gets called, do your quartz drawing on the context given.

Answer (score 1):

This can be an excellent start up tutorial for Quartz core

[Quartz Core Sample From Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/QuartzDemo/QuartzDemo.zip)

This includes all basic drawings. No doubt you will need to optimize that.